# content-type to be used for uploading svg images to AWS S3

Tags: svg, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mime-types, content-type

I was trying to upload `*.svg` images to S3 without specifying any Content-type. This upload works successfully and AWS sets Content-Type as binary/octet-stream by default. Now, when I try to use S3 URL of image in my browser, the browser does not render the image and throws incorrect mime-type warning.

To set the correct mime-type I checked list of Content-type which AWS offers but it does not have `"image/svg+xml"`.

So I wanted to know if anyone has tried to upload SVG images to S3? What is the content-type set in that case? Or is there any other compatible Content-type that can be used for uploading SVG images to S3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you mentioned, the correct Content-Type for SVG files is "image/svg+xml".

Even if the AWS console does not provide that value in the Content-Type selection field, you can enter it anyway and S3 will accept it.

AWS specifies the following in their API docs for the Content-Type header:

> A standard MIME type describing the format of the contents. For more information, go to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: binary/octet-stream
>
> Valid Values: MIME types
>
> Constraints: None

For additional details see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: Thanks dcro.. It worked for me, I was trying to upload using old version of s3cmd. And thus, even if I tried to upload with Content-type header, it was giving me error.

Comment: This isn't handled at the S3 layer; it's handled at the application layer. You didn't mention _how_ you were uploading files in your original post.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I was trying to upload using s3cmd commands. (http://s3tools.org/s3cmd). I wanted to set mime-type for specific files. Now, I am doing this by using --mime-type param of s3cmd.

Note: Sorry, for a very delayed response. I did'nt get any notifications for any comments on this question. :(

Comment: @RyanParman, can you please help me with this question-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356880/uploading-to-aws-s3-as-text-javascript-while-using-s3cmd

Comment: @UW20989 Did using the 'image/svg+xml' type work for you? Any time I upload an png/jpeg/gif it works, but if I upload an svg I get a 403 and it says my signature isn't correct. I'm not changing code, so it must be the content-type that it doesn't like.

Comment: Yes, chapmand it does work for me.. What version of s3cmd you are using? As far as I remember even I had got this error & upgrading to latest version resolved it.. Please try version-1.5.0-alpha1 of s3cmd.

e.g. s3cmd -c s3cmd.cfg --verbose --acl-public --mime-type='image/svg+xml' put --add-header='Cache-Control:max-age=2600000, public'  <source> <destination>

Answer (score 2):

For those using an SDK, here's an example code snippet that I used to solve this problem. Im using Javascript (NodeJs). This is to complement the accepted answer above, which is to explicitly define the **ContentType** as **'image/svg+xml'** from the params before uploading.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket', 
    Key: 'key', 
    Body: stream,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: 'image/svg+xml',
 };
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass content type static and get file from public path not in request then used this:

```
$destinationPath = public_path("/images/".$image_name); 
if (File::exists($destinationPath)) 
{
    $contents = File::get($destinationPath);
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($image_name,$contents,['mimetype' => 'image/svg+xml'],'public');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've problems with uploaded files svg to s3 in laravel; but works with next code:

```
$image = Storage::disk('s3')->put(
            $filePath,
            file_get_contents($file),
            $file->getClientOriginalExtension() === 'svg' ? ['mimetype' => 'image/svg+xml'] : []
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood from one of the other answers that you're using `s3cmd` to upload the files to S3. The package makes some educated guesses about MIME type for each file based on the file extension (there's a useful explanation [here](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/wiki/Understand-Content-Type,-Mime-type-guessing-and-Magic)).

There are also a range of options to `s3cmd` including the `--no-mime-magic` command flag (see https://s3tools.org/usage for info), which helped with CSS and other files, but not with SVG.

To get this to work for my own purposes I had to set a specific Content-Type for only SVG files using include/exclude command flags:

`s3cmd sync --content-type 'image/svg+xml' --exclude '*' --include '*.svg' {local source} {S3 bucket URL}`

Because I also have other content I had to have a separate `s3cmd` command to sync everything else:

`s3cmd sync --no-mime-magic --content-type 'image/svg+xml' --exclude '*.svg' {local source} {S3 bucket URL}`